# What does synchronized do in this section?

Tags: android, kotlin, synchronized

I do not understand exactly what synchronized does in this code

```
fun getDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase{
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if(tempInstance != null){
            return tempInstance
        }
        synchronized(this){
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                UserDatabase::class.java, "user_database"
            ).build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
```

Comment: It is a Singleton pattern that *should* use double checked locking, however this implementation is not double checked - which is a problem here. The idea of the synchronised block is to make sure the same single `UserDatabase` is returned no matter which thread, or how many threads call it simultaneously.  https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton-double-checked-locking